# Is Pakistan Military behind the deposition of former PM Nawaz Sharif?

Tags: pakistan

When Pakistan's former PM Nawaz Sharif was [declared incompetent](https://www.dawn.com/news/1348191) to carry on as a PM because of [telling lies](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/asia/pakistan-prime-minister-nawaz-sharif-corruption-supreme-court-disqualified-oust-kicked-out-charges-a7864116.html) and doing [corruptions](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2017/jul/28/pakistani-court-disqualifies-pm-nawaz-sharif-from-office), he indirectly accused Pakistan Military and Judiciary's nexus behind his removal.

- [Former PM accuses army of orchestrating dismissal](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2018/05/pakistan-pm-accuses-army-orchestrating-dismissal-180523153801682.html)
- [Judiciary, military have become my enemies: Nawaz Sharif](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/world/pakistan/judiciary-military-have-become-my-enemies-nawaz-sharif/articleshow/62971636.cms)

I have two questions in this regard:

1. Is Military-Judiciary nexus behind the deposition of former PM Nawaz Sharif?
2. How does that work?

Comment: We require notable sources that claimed that those two claims you posted were true.  Please edit them in or it's likely that your question will be deleted.

Comment: Even in the best of circumstances this would devolve into a he said/she said thing, and absent any credible sources it's just a shouting match.

Comment: Well, we have a notable claim or two at least...

Comment: In 1993 Prime Minster Sharif was forced out by the military, in 1999 he was deposed in a military coup and convicted in a military court, and in 2017 he was disqualified as Prime Minster by the civilian courts for failing to disclose in his nomination papers his employment by a Dubai-based company after the Army Chief had called for full accountability for revelations in the Panama Papers.  The Pakistan courts have been more friendly to military leaders than to elected representatives since [coups starting in the 1950s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_coups_in_Pakistan)

Comment: @Henry, can you present any reference citation in favor of your comment as this is not an opinion-based website.